# Fire jQuery .on('change') always at least once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I often find myself using pieces of code like the following:

```
$('[name=myradio]').on('change', function(){

    if($(this).val() == 0){
        $('#div').toggle();
    }

    else if(....){
        $('#div2').toggle();
    }

    //...and more code going on
});
```

However, often I want to execute these pieces of code always at least once (for example when validation fails)! Of course I could make a method of this code and then execute the method from within the `change` anonymous function, as wel as in a `$(document).ready()` method, but I wonder if there is an easy way to execute that code at least once but also keep that code only in the change method to keep everything nice and clean instead of making a method for something that would be used only twice.

Comment: How would you do it without using a method?

Comment: That's actually my question... is that possible? Maybe there's a way to execute the 'change' once at least, which is what I'm searching for so I don't need to make a method for such a small piece of code that's only used like twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just trigger change in `$(document).ready(...)`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[name=myradio]').on('change', function() {

    if ($(this).val() == 0) {
      $('#div').toggle();
    } else if (....) {
      $('#div2').toggle();
    }

    //...and more code going on
  }).trigger("change");
});
```

Comment: Well that was easier than I thought it would be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method. This way you can keep the code only in the change method and trigger it from anywhere.

`$(selector).trigger("change");`